# Dhtmlxgrid 4.0 doesn't load data from the ASP.Net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dhtmlx

In my ASP.Net MVC web application I used to have dhtmlxgrid plugin v 3.5 and now updated to v4.0.
Before it was easy to generate dynamic values for the grid in separate .cshtml view and only pass the url of the method inlo loadXML like this:

```
myGrid.loadXML('@Url.Action("XmlValues")');
```

Now in the version 4.0 they replaced loadXML() with load(), which still should be able to do the same thing. But instead of parsing the data into the grid it shows an alert with an xml code generated inside the view and the table body is empty. It can't even load simple xml if it was passes through the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <row id="1">
        <cell>1</cell>
        <cell>2</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

But if I copy that into an external xml file and pass path to the file into the method it works correctly.

```
myGrid.load("/xml.xml");
```

What is the problem with new load() method and how to make it work with dynamic data in ASP.Net MVC as I used to?

Answer (score 0):

please make sure there are no extra chars in the generated xml. For example, a space (" ") before the xml header.